# Lipschitz continuity and boundedness of derivatives.

Tags: continuity, partial-derivative

Suppose $f(x)$ is a function that has derivative in the domain of our concern. We all know that if the derivative is bounded then $f$ is Lipschitz continuous. I was wondering if the above statement is an if-and-only-if statement since if the derivative is unbounded then surely we can find two points that fail the Lipschitz continuity property?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is.

Assume that $ f$ is differentiable and  Lipschitz at $ A$, then there exists some $K>0$ such that for all $(x,x_0)$ in $A$, with $x\ne x_0$ ,

$$|\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}|\le K$$

then if we pass to the limit when $x\to x_0$,

$$|f'(x_0)|\le K$$

the derivative is necessarily bounded at $A$.